# Alter custom ID column name Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

We are transforming an old project to Laravel 7
the users table doesn't follow laravel naming
the id column is named "UserId" and the problem it is not auto increment

I already set in the User model

```
protected $primaryKey = 'UserId';
```

how can I alter the column to be Auto-Increment, keep in mind it is used in foreign constraints, thank you

Answer (score 0):

If the name of the user table is different, you should specify this naming in the model section. Also, why not change the related column type of the migration process to include auto-increment. To set the auto-increment property, in the model part `protected $incrementing = true;` You can specify.